# Correct way to join a new Windows guest to a domain when deployed form a template

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am attempting to automate the deployment of a Windows guest in a VMware environment and I have been quite able to do so as long as I am happy with having to manually add it to the domain, which I am not. I have tried using the vmware_client customization and it does not appear to even be applied.

Ansible 2.9
Red Hat 8

YML

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/all
    - build_info/vars
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: "{{ dusername }}" 
    - name: Clone a virtual machine from Windows template and customize 
      vmware_guest:
        annotation: "This machine was built from a template through a process triggered by an ansible playbook"
        hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}"
        datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
        cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
        folder: "{{ folder }}"
        name: "{{ bname }}"
        template: "{{ template }}"
        datastore: "{{ datastore}}"
        state: poweredon
        networks:
          - name: "{{ bnetworks.netname }}"
            ip: "{{ bnetworks.ip }}"
            netmask: "{{ bnetworks.netmask }}"
            gateway: "{{ bnetworks.gateway }}"
            domain: "{{ bnetworks.domain }}"
            start_connected: yes
            dns_servers: "{{bnetworks.dns_servers}}"
            dns_suffix: "{{bnetworks.dns_suffix}}"
        customization:
          hostname: "{{ bname }}"
          domainadmin: "{{ dusername }}"
          domainadminpassword: "{{ dpassword }}"
          joindomain: "{{ bnetworks.domain }}"
          fullname: "{{ ladminname }}"
        wait_for_ip_address: yes
        wait_for_customization: yes
      with_dict: "{{ bnetworks }}"
      delegate_to: localhost'
```

The result

```
{
    "changed": true,
    "instance": {
        "module_hw": true,
        "hw_name": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
        "hw_power_status": "poweredOn",
        "hw_guest_full_name": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)",
        "hw_guest_id": "windows9Server64Guest",
        "hw_product_uuid": "4227f81c-1b25-13fd-45f2-d9399408a5f6",
        "hw_processor_count": 2,
        "hw_cores_per_socket": 1,
        "hw_memtotal_mb": 8192,
        "hw_interfaces": [
            "eth0"
        ],
        "hw_datastores": [
            "na2-tntr02-dat"
        ],
        "hw_files": [
            "[na2-tntr02-dat] ********/********.vmx",
            "[na2-tntr02-dat] ********/********.nvram",
            "[na2-tntr02-dat] ********/********.vmsd",
            "[na2-tntr02-dat] ********/********.vmxf",
            "[na2-tntr02-dat] ********/********.vmdk"
        ],
        "hw_esxi_host": "na2-devesx01.********",
        "hw_guest_ha_state": true,
        "hw_is_template": false,
        "hw_folder": "/NA2/vm/GLOBAL OPERATIONS/Storage",
        "hw_version": "vmx-13",
        "instance_uuid": "5027d0ef-7a89-73a6-1da9-6e15df083592",
        "guest_tools_status": "guestToolsRunning",
        "guest_tools_version": "11269",
        "guest_question": null,
        "guest_consolidation_needed": false,
        "ipv4": "10.6.6.10",
        "ipv6": null,
        "annotation": "This machine was built from a template through a process triggered by an ansible playbook",
        "customvalues": {},
        "snapshots": [],
        "current_snapshot": null,
        "vnc": {},
        "moid": "vm-21984",
        "vimref": "vim.VirtualMachine:vm-21984",
        "hw_cluster": "NA2-NonPROD",
        "hw_eth0": {
            "addresstype": "assigned",
            "label": "Network adapter 1",
            "macaddress": "00:50:56:a7:fc:87",
            "ipaddresses": [
                "fe80::4835:d689:f1a7:6dd4",
                "10.6.6.10"
            ],
            "macaddress_dash": "00-50-56-a7-fc-87",
            "summary": "DVSwitch: 50 27 7a 36 e1 9e ae 1a-29 5a 4a 79 8d 2b 6f a3",
            "portgroup_portkey": "191",
            "portgroup_key": "dvportgroup-71"
        }
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "annotation": "This machine was built from a template through a process triggered by an ansible playbook",
            "hostname": "na2-pdvcva01.********",
            "username": "RP4VM@vsphere.local",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "validate_certs": false,
            "datacenter": "NA2",
            "cluster": "NA2-NonPROD",
            "folder": "/GLOBAL OPERATIONS/Storage",
            "name": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "template": "NA2_ZWindows2016STD",
            "datastore": "na2-tntr02-dat",
            "state": "poweredon",
            "networks": [
                {
                    "name": "FIRM_NA|PROD_ap|STORAGE_epg",
                    "ip": "10.6.6.10",
                    "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                    "gateway": "10.6.6.1",
                    "domain": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "start_connected": true,
                    "dns_servers": [
                        "10.6.2.16",
                        "10.2.2.17"
                    ],
                    "dns_suffix": [
                        "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "asia.global-legal.com",
                        "emea.global-legal.com"
                    ],
                    "type": "static"
                }
            ],
            "customization": {
                "hostname": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "domainadmin": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "domainadminpassword": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "joindomain": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "fullname": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER"
            },
            "wait_for_ip_address": true,
            "wait_for_customization": true,
            "port": 443,
            "is_template": false,
            "customvalues": [],
            "name_match": "first",
            "use_instance_uuid": false,
            "disk": [],
            "cdrom": [],
            "hardware": {},
            "force": false,
            "state_change_timeout": 0,
            "linked_clone": false,
            "vapp_properties": [],
            "proxy_host": null,
            "proxy_port": null,
            "uuid": null,
            "guest_id": null,
            "esxi_hostname": null,
            "snapshot_src": null,
            "resource_pool": null,
            "customization_spec": null,
            "convert": null
        }
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "item": {
        "key": "netname",
        "value": "FIRM_NA|PROD_ap|STORAGE_epg"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "_ansible_item_label": {
        "key": "netname",
        "value": "FIRM_NA|PROD_ap|STORAGE_epg"
    },
    "_ansible_delegated_vars": {}
}
```

However the machine does not join the domain. I fully expect a fail because the domain credentials supplied do not have the authority to add the machine to the domain.

Comment: When the machine is built and running, can you login to it and join it manually using the domain credentials you supplied to the playbook.  Your last sentence says you suspected this, so please confirm this and get that resolved (then it would not be an Ansible problem).

Comment: @dan_linder No I cannot join the domain using the credentials supplied as I expected not to. However, wouldn't there be a fail with some message like: Not authorized? The play book merrily says everything went as expected. It is almost as if the play progresses faster than the VM is built and pushes the customizations before it is able to join the domain.

Comment: Additional information: It appears that nothing in the customization block is being acted on. I added the fullname: parameter to change the local administrator's name and that did not work either.